# TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined, In ContactComponent.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, jsx

Contact.render

F:/React/confusion/src/components/ContactComponent.js:133

```
<Input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"
  placeholder="First Name"
  value={this.state.firstname}
  valid={errors.firstname === ''}
  invalid={errors.firstname !== ''}
  onBlur={this.handleBlur('firstname')}
  onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

github:https://github.com/KhushalAbrol/KhushalAbrol--Ristorante-Con-Fusion-React-

please tell me why this error is coming?

Comment: Commit:  c250b1926ddea57c61fffa28179a202c8c3ae647

Comment: Welcome to SO, notice that it isn't a debug service, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You are accessing some value `firstname` of an undefined object on line 133, i.e. `errors` ***must*** be undefined. Follow the trail...

```
valid={errors.firstname === ''}
```

You don't return `errors` from your [`validate`](https://github.com/KhushalAbrol/KhushalAbrol--Ristorante-Con-Fusion-React-/blob/master/src/components/ContactComponent.js#L54-L79) function, so it is undefined on [line 82](https://github.com/KhushalAbrol/KhushalAbrol--Ristorante-Con-Fusion-React-/blob/master/src/components/ContactComponent.js#L82).

```
const errors = this.validate(
  this.state.firstname,
  this.state.lastname,
  this.state.telnum,
  this.state.email
);
```

## Solution

Return `errors` at the end of the validation function.

```
validate(firstname, lastname, telnum, email) {
    const errors = {
        firstname: '',
        lastname: '',
        telnum: '',
        email: '',
    };

    if (this.state.touched.firstname && firstname.length <=3)
        errors.firstname = 'First Name should be >=3 characters'
    else if (this.state.touched.firstname && firstname.length >=10)
        errors.firstname = 'First Name should be <=10 characters'

    if (this.state.touched.lastname && lastname.length <=3)
        errors.lastname = 'Last Name should be >=3 characters'
    else if (this.state.touched.lastname && lastname.length >=10)
        errors.lastname = 'Last Name should be <=10 characters'

    const reg = /^\d+$/;
    if (this.state.touched.telnum && !reg.test(telnum))
        errors.telnum = 'Last Name should contain only '
    
    if (this.state.touched.email && email.split('').filter(x => x === '@').length !==1)
        errors.email = 'mail should contain a \'@\' '

    return errors; // <-- return errors object for consumption
}
```

## Suggestion

When you get errors, please read all of the message, they generally include line numbers and stacktraces, and tell you right where the issue is. This is what they are there for. Please also include your relevant code ***IN*** your question as git repos have a tendency to mutate or time, or even relocate entirely, but the code should included here for future readers.